# iPhone- How to get the main view (1st view) every time when we switching form one tab to another tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my iPhone app, I have used **tabbarcontroller in that i have 4 tabs for four different items**

*In each tab i have different views navigate transaction in those.*

**my requirement** is, **when i switch form on tab to another tab by taping on tabbar item**.

T***`the main view (first view ) of each tab has to be appeared instead of currently working view.`***

For ex:

1. I select tab 3 there i do some operations and navigate to some 2nd view in the third tab.
2. and then i secet tab 4 and then again tab3.. then the previously woriking view view 2 presents in tab3,

   1. But **i need to present 1st view at any time when i select tab 3** (Same like in any other tabs)

how to do..

Comment: Do u have a navigationController in the 2nd view of a tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a subclass of UINavigationController, change the class of any navigation controllers you have in your storyboard to that class, and put this code in that subclass:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Whenever you click on another tab, this method will be called, and it will reset the navigation stack back to the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller or appdelegate as delegate of your tabbarcontroller. implement this delegate function

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
  int selectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
  NSArray *tabbarControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;

  //Then replace tabbarControllers[selectedIndex] by your new view controller(with navigation controller) 

   tabBarController.viewControllers = Your replaced Array;
}
```